# How to disable Code Inspection gutter icons in Rider Editor?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Can anyone tell me please how to disable this icon from appearing in my Rider window? It allows configuring highlighting levels.

[image: Icon here]

Incidently I would also like to hide that bar it appears on as it doesn't have any purpose.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd-party plugins installed (Preferences/Settings | Plugins)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Call the context menu for the "Pencils" icon (click on the right mouse click)
- "Move to status bar"
- Then go to View | Appearance | Status bar widgets | Pencils
  [image: where to find it in UI]

Comment: Eventually I figured out how to move it to status bar, which is fine by me now. I don't get the View | Appearance | Status bar widgets | Pencils option. I'm on MacOS.

Comment: I use macOS as well. I've added a picture to show where to find this menu item. Hope it helps.

Comment: Pencils options now showing in "JetBrains Rider 2022.3.1" on mac